# add "OK" button at bottom of the multi select dropdown bbotstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css

[bootstrap multiselect dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVjWp.png)

I want to add button at the bottom of the dropdown when I  scroll  drop-down button should be constant means fixed at the bottom.
I am using http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#getting-started link for the multi select dropdown.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I done with that ok button by using sumoselect jquery plugin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope this will help

https://github.com/HemantNegi/jquery.sumoselect

Sumo Select provides OK button at bottom of drop down.